# facebook API v5 feed since date not working

Tags: php, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

So im getting the feed for a page using the Facebook SDK, but im trying to add the "since", so get all post from the date.

but for some reason its not working at all, its just keeps showing all the posts, rather than by the date i specified.

Here is what i have using the Graph API

```
"406433779383/feed?fields=id,message,picture,link,shares,created_time,comments.limit(1),likes.limit(1)&since=1457453444"
```

is this not part of the API anymore, or am i just not writing it correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is not working with user access token but if you use APP Access token it will start working.